# PDOCrud + Routing libraries don't work together due to htaccess, why?

Tags: .htaccess

I am using this [library](https://pdocrud.com) for all my CRUD operations, as well as [this](https://phprouter.com/) for the routing.

WhenI try to "Add, edit or delete" I get `404 not found`

[image]

After investigating around, I found that the issue was with the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.svg|\.js)$
RewriteRule (.*) routes.php [QSA,L]

# BEGIN Pdocrud
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# HTML
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>

# END Pdocrud
```

The first 3 lines are responsible for the routing. When I remove them PDOCrud works, but then my url will be `localhost/public/view/reports.view.php` instead of `localhost/cases-reports`.

How can I reconstruct the `.htaccess` to make it work?

**PDOCrudAjaxCtrl.php**

```
<?php

@session_start();

Class PDOCrudAjaxCtrl {

    public function handleRequest() {
        $instanceKey = $_REQUEST["pdocrud_instance"];
        if(!isset($_SESSION["pdocrud_sess"][$instanceKey])){
            die("Session has been expired. Please refresh your page to continue.");
        }

        $pdocrud = unserialize($_SESSION["pdocrud_sess"][$instanceKey]);
        $action = $_POST["pdocrud_data"]["action"];
        $data = $_POST["pdocrud_data"];
        $post = $_POST;
        if (isset($_FILES))
            $post = array_merge($_FILES, $post);
        $data["post"] = $post;
        switch (strtoupper($action)) {
            case "VIEW":
                echo $pdocrud->render("VIEWFORM", $data);
                break;
            case "SORT":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $data["action"] = "asc";
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "ASC":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "DESC":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "ADD":
                echo $pdocrud->render("INSERTFORM", $data);
                break;
            case "INSERT":
                $pdocrud->render("INSERT", $post);
                break;
            case "INSERT_CLOSE":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->render("INSERT", $post);
                break;
            case "INSERT_BACK":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->render("INSERT", $post);
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "BACK":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "EDIT":
                $pdocrud->setInlineEdit(false);
                echo $pdocrud->render("EDITFORM", $data);
                break;
            case "INLINE_EDIT":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->setInlineEdit(true);
                echo $pdocrud->render("EDITFORM", $data);
                break;
            case "ONEPAGEEDIT":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->setInlineEdit(false);
                echo $pdocrud->render("ONEPAGE", $data);
                break;
            case "ONEPAGEVIEW":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("ONEPAGE", $data);
                break;
            case "QUICK_VIEW":
                echo $pdocrud->render("QUICKVIEW", $data);
                break;
            case "RELATED_TABLE":
                echo $pdocrud->render("RELATED_TABLE", $data);
                break;
            case "INLINE_BACK":
                $pdocrud->render("UPDATE", $post);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "UPDATE":
                $pdocrud->render("UPDATE", $post);
                break;
            case "UPDATE_BACK":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->render("UPDATE", $post);
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "UPDATE_CLOSE":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->render("UPDATE", $post);
                break;
            case "DELETE":
                $pdocrud->render("DELETE", $data);
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "DELETE_SELECTED":
                $pdocrud->render("DELETE_SELECTED", $data);
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "PAGINATION":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->currentPage($data["page"]);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "RECORDS_PER_PAGE":
                $pdocrud->currentPage(1);
                $pdocrud->recordsPerPage($data["records"]);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "SEARCH":
                $pdocrud->currentPage(1);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "AUTOSUGGEST":
                if(isset($_GET["callback"]))
                    $data["callback"] = $_GET["callback"];
                echo $pdocrud->render("AUTOSUGGEST", $data);
                break;
            case "EXPORTTABLE":
                echo $pdocrud->render("EXPORTTABLE", $data);
                break;
            case "EXPORTFORM":
                $pdocrud->render("EXPORTFORM", $data);
                break;
            case "SWITCH":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->render("SWITCH", $data);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "BTNSWITCH":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->render("BTNSWITCH", $data);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "LOADDEPENDENT":
                echo $pdocrud->render("LOADDEPENDENT", $data);
                break;
            case "EMAIL" : echo $pdocrud->render("EMAIL", $post);
                break;
            case "SELECT":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "SELECTFORM":
                echo $pdocrud->render("SELECT", $post);
                break;
            case "FILTER":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->currentPage(1);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "RELOAD":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "SAVE_CRUD_TABLE_DATA":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->render("SAVE_CRUD_DATA", $data);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "RENDER_ADV_SEARCH":
                $pdocrud->currentPage(1);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "DATE_RANGE_REPORT":
                $pdocrud->setBackOperation();
                $pdocrud->currentPage(1);
                echo $pdocrud->render("CRUD", $data);
                break;
            case "CLONE":
                echo $pdocrud->render("CLONEFORM", $data);
                break;
            case "CELL_UPDATE":
                $updateData[$data["column"]] = $data["content"];
                 if (isset($data["id"]))
                    $pdocrud->setPrimarykeyValue($data["id"]);
                $pdocrud->render("UPDATE", $updateData);
                break;
            case "AJAX_ACTION":
                echo $pdocrud->render("AJAX_ACTION", $data);
                break;   
            case "PRINTPDF":
                echo $pdocrud->render("PRINT_PDF", $data);
                break;    
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, please do mention which url you are hitting in browser and from what url it should get serve in backend?

Comment: I am using Largon webserver, which auto generates virtual host for me. `http://refactored-dashboard.test/`

Comment: Sorry its still not clear. For your statement ` "Add, edit or delete" I get 404 not found` could you please post samples of links which are actually behind these aliases(Add/edit/delete).

Comment: Well, PDOCrud is a library, I didn't make any of these links. It's not recommended to mess with it. documentation: https://pdocrud.com/demo/pages/index

Comment: I didn't mean to mess with any of library etc :) I meant is since you have posted htaccess rules and you want it to be fixed so for that we need these kind of basic information, cheers.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question. `PDOCrudAjaxCtrl.php`

Comment: I have the repo: https://github.com/DevMushref/refactored-dashboard/tree/master/script

Comment: Dear, any updates?

Comment: Did it solve the problem? I have also run into the same

Comment: @Smaran No sadly, I ended up ditching the library because of so many things are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.zip|\.css|\.svg|\.js)$
> RewriteRule (.*) routes.php [QSA,L]
>
> # BEGIN Pdocrud
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php 
> </IfModule>
> ```

The first rule rewrites everything to `routes.php` so the second rule is not even processed. You need to reverse these two rules for this to make any sense. However, it should be noted that the presence of both these systems would appear to impose a "silent" restriction on the type of URLs you can implement as "routes".

However, the second rule is not strictly correct anyway since it is potentially rewriting to a different URL than the one being tested in the preceding *condition* (which could potentially result in a rewrite-loop, ie. a 500 error, for certain requests. See [the following question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error) for more detail on this).

Try the following instead (assuming the `.htaccess` file is in the document root):

```
RewriteEngine On

# BEGIN Pdocrud
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php|png|jpe?g|gif|zip|css|svg|js)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On
# HTML
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
# END Pdocrud

RewriteRule !\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg|zip|css|svg|js)$ routes.php [L]
```

Additional notes:

- In the "Pdocrud" rule that appends the `.php` extension, there is no point checking that the request does not map to a directory only to then check that it does map to a file.
- In your "routing" rule, the preceding condition was not required - this check should be performed in the `RewriteRule` instead. Likewise, the `QSA` flag was not required.
- A restriction with this config is you cannot have a "route" that also happens to map to a `.php` file (when `.php` is appended).